# How to get GPS location from Windows using Java

Tags: java, windows, geolocation, gps

How can I obtain the current GPS location of a Windows 10 tablet PC using Java. The PC has an integrated GPS device. Thanks for your Help.

Comment: On Windows 10 you can use the [Geolocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator) class.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution using Java

Comment: So then, use it from Java. It's a COM interface, and as such language-agnostic, provided you have the required plumbing in place.